# Best solution advice for backup to NAS over WAN

Tags: ubuntu, backup, nas

What is the best solution for daily backup of Linux folder to NAS server over WAN? Here is the situation: My customer has expressed a wish that source code for his project must be backed up every day on my local server and then exported to his NAS. He gave me access to NAS via FTP protocol, and now I want to use cron scheduler for ftp upload to his server. Is this OK, and how is this done?

Comment: `rsync` command in a script and script inside `cron.daily`

Comment: Relevant: [How can this backup strategy work?](http://superuser.com/a/622821)

Comment: use ssh and ssh-keys for authentication.

Comment: @terdon No offence, but that script is a tad zany ("zany" as in "overkill").

Comment: @goldilocks it is for this question, yes, that's why I only posted a comment. It's not overkill for the SU post though, is it?

Comment: @terdon No.  I actually did not read that question (until now) but it seems to have some specific requirements that aren't part of this one.  I just wanted to note this in case the OP looks at that and goes *"Whaa?"*.  Of course if he gets it that's all good.

Comment: @goldilocks yes indeed, that would be overkill. I just thought it was relevant since it showed one way of doing this using `rsync` and `cron`. It is far more complex than requested here, yes.

Comment: Ok, I do not have a lot of data to transfer, every day about 200 mega bytes. For the first backup of this repository, I've created on local server a scripts that is called from cron every day and the scripts copies repository (svn) and dumps some database into directory which is named with current date-time. This copy is what I would like to transfer to NAS over WAN. Which ftp client supports command line username, password, host and host dir parameters?

Comment: What do you need FTP for? You need to explain the details of your setup (please [edit] your post, don't add info in comments) and explain how you access your NAS for us to be able to give you precise information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments `rsync` is a good tool to use.  Basic rsync usage simply mirrors a directory.  For example:

```
rsync -a --delete /source/dir /backup/dir
```

Will make the backup directory match the source; if there is stuff in the backup that isn't in the source, it will be deleted (`--delete`), and if there is stuff that is in both, it will be updated in the backup *if* the timestamp in the source is more recent (i.e., the file has changed).

**Note you can also use `rsync` via SSH if you don't have the remote directory locally mounted** (and the NAS machine also runs an ssh server).

```
rsync -a --delete user@ip:/source/dir /backup/dir
```

This requires that you keep the mirror directory on your backup machine.  If you want rolling backups, you could then archive and compress this:

```
tar -cjf  backup.tb2 /source/dir
```

This can then be extracted with `tar -xjf backup.tb2`.  To prevent each backup from overwriting the last, you could use a timestamp:

```
tar -cjf backup.`date +%m%d%y`.tb2 /source/dir
```

This will produce a filename with a MMDDYY timestamp in it such as `backup.030814.tb2`.

So, that's a two line script you can execute daily via cron.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach, assuming you want to back up folder `/foo` would be to create a simple little `crontab` to run `rsync` daily.

1. Create your `crontab` by running `crontab -e`. In the editor window that will appear, add this line (assuming your NAS is mounted locally, you can use `ssh` if not):

   ```
   @daily rsync -glprtu /foo /path/to/NAS/mount
   ```
2. Close the editor window. That's it, your folder will now be backed up to your NAS daily.

The `rsync` options used in this example are:

```
-g, --group                 preserve group
-l, --links                 copy symlinks as symlinks
-p, --perms                 preserve permissions
-r, --recursive             recurse into directories
-t, --times                 preserve modification times
-u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
```

I suggest you read through `man rsync` for more options, it is a very powerful tool. You might, for example, be interested in

```
--delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
-z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
-C, --cvs-exclude           auto-ignore files in the same way CVS does
```

---

**UPDATE:** If you *need* to do this via ftp, I recommend you [mount his NAS locally](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-mount-ftp-folder-to-local-directory-in-ubuntu.html) first:

1. Install `curlftps`

   ```
   sudo aptitude install curlftpfs
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/fstab` and add a line for the NAS:

   ```
   curlftpfs#ftpUsername:ftpPassword@ftp://ftpUrl /localDirectory fuse rw,uid=1000,umask=0777,user,suid,allow_other,exec,auto,utf8  0   1
   ```

Then, point your `rsync` command to the local mountpoint.

Comment: But /path/to/NAS/mount must be local, i have ftp address of NAS.

Comment: @MarkoFrelih you'll have to mount the FTP server locally. See updated answer for a way to do that.

Comment: Wow, did not know that mounting FTP server locally is possible. Thanks for hint, now I am digging into docs and work! Thanks for very useful guideline!

Comment: I've succesfully solved the problem, but the operation of copying itself is so slow that I think it is unusable! 20 megabytes were copied in 4 hours!

Comment: Are there any workarounds to accelerate copy process?

Comment: @MarkoFrelih we have no idea what kind of network you and your customer are using. Normal home networks usually have very slow upload speeds, perhaps that is the limit of the transfer speed (doubtful but it depends on where you are). For all I know you're connecting using a 14.4Kbs modem. Please post a new question, giving details of the issue, explaining that you are restricted to FTP, clarifying whether another protocol (such as ssh) is an option and what exactly you need to do.